# Finding the equation of hyperbola

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the equation of the hyperbola with vertices $(\pm 6, 0)$ and one of the directrix is $x=4$.

Comment: perhaps you can google for similar problems

Comment: @Matt I don't know where to start from

Comment: Mathematics SE is not a site for answering homework problems

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

What's the center of the hyperbola?

What are equations of major & minor axes?

If the required equation is $$\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1,$$

$a=6$

What are the equation of the directrixes?